# Django exclude problems

Tags: django

Can anyone explain this to me?

```
class EventBlock(models.Model):
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, blank=True, null=True)

class EventSlot(models.Model):
    event_block = models.ForeignKey(EventBlock)

>>> EventSlot.objects.count()
>>> 446

>>> EventSlot.objects.filter(event_block__created_by__groups__name='Manager').count()
>>> 438

>>> EventSlot.objects.exclude(event_block__created_by__groups__name='Manager').count()
>>> 446
```

Surely, if there are 438 matches on the filter, then the exclude should remove those 438 matches, leaving 8? But it hasn't removed any of the matches. I'm confused.

Comment: OK, done. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you might get unexpected results because the `created_by` user belongs to other groups as well as the 'Manager' group.

You could rearrange your query by getting a list of managers first.

```
managers = User.objects.filter(groups__name='Manager')
EventSlot.objects.filter(event_block__created_by__in=managers)
EventSlot.objects.exclude(event_block__created_by__in=managers)
```